# How to find the in-memory address of a specific instruction in a DLL

Tags: windows, security, dll, exploit, shellcode

How can I find the in-memory address (for exploit writing) of a specific instruction?

Specifically, I'm looking for a `call ebp` instruction in `user32.dll` on Windows XP with no Service Pack whose address I can point `EIP` to.  I have both [Immunity Debugger](https://www.immunityinc.com/products-immdbg.shtml) and [OllyDBG](http://www.ollydbg.de/download.htm) installed on the target.

Comment: Well, DLLs are relocatable (and _are being_ relocated) so you can only ever find such an address relative to the module's base address in a reliable manner.

Comment: @Damon that is true with all modern OSes, but With Windows XP there is no ASLR, so the in-memory location of DLLs is very consistent between OS versions and SP versions.

Comment: I wasn't even thinking of ASLR, though that would be another issue of course. I was thinking of the normal DLL rebasing which routinely takes place. All DLLs usually have the same base address (though it's possible to tell the linker to choose a random one, but this fragments the address space even more nastily...) and are rebased as they're loaded. The first DLL is usually kernel32, loaded at its original address. Then it's usually NLS and then all other DLLs (including user32), all of which are relocated. Incidentially they may end up at the same addresses every time, but who knows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find an instruction, you need to figure out where the code, .text, section starts and ends, then load the DLL and just do liner search until you find the instruction.

Here we have a test DLL that has two `call ebp` instructions:

```
// test.c
// gcc -Wall -shared test.c -o test.dll
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport) void test(void) {
    asm("call *%ebp");
    puts("test");
    asm("call *%ebp");
}
```

Compile it and load the DLL in ollydbg and click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search for `CALL EBP`:

```
6BEC125A  |. FFD5            CALL EBP
6BEC125C  |. C70424 6430EC6> MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],test.6BEC3064 ; |ASCII "test"
6BEC1263  |. E8 74060000     CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.puts>              ; \puts
6BEC1268  |. FFD5            CALL EBP
```

you see the address of the first instruction is at `0x6bec125a` the second at `0x6bec1268`. The opcode of `call ebp` is `0xff 0xd5`, remember this.

Now we need to find the boundaries of the code, you can use objdump with `-h`:

```
> objdump --headers test.dll

test.dll:     file format pei-i386

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000984  6bec1000  6bec1000  00000600  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE, DATA

  1 .data         00000008  6bec2000  6bec2000  00001000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA

  2 .rdata        0000011c  6bec3000  6bec3000  00001200  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  ....

>
```

the code starts at VMA, virtual memory address, `0x6bec1000` and its size is `0x984`, so it ends at `0x6bec1000` + `0x984` = `0x6bec1984` as :

```
0x6bec1000
....
what is between are the DLL instructions
....
0x6bec1984
```

I hope that was clear so far.

If we want to code our `call ebp` scanner, we need to do the flowing:

1. Read the PE information and get the executable section information, usually `.text`, to find its relative address and its virtual size.
2. Load the DLL using [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms684175%28VS.85%29.aspx), it will return the base address of the DLL.
3. The virtual address of the beginning of the code section is: DLL base address + code section virtualAddress and it ends at DLL base address + code section virtualAddress + VirtualSize.
4. Now we are ready to loop through the code and look for `0xff 0xd5`, `call ebp`'s opcode, simple liner search.

Here is a simple implementation:

```
// findopcode.c
// gcc -Wall findopcode.c -o findopcode

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const char opcode[] = {0xff, 0xd5}; // The opcode of `call ebp'
    FILE *dllFile;
    HMODULE dllHandle;

    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS NtHeaders;
    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sectionHeader;

    unsigned int i;
    unsigned char *starAddr;
    unsigned char *endAddr;

    if( argc < 2 ) {
        printf("usage: %s [DLL]\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    if( ( dllFile = fopen(argv[1], "rb") ) == NULL ) {
        perror("[!] Error");
        return -1;
    }

    // Read the basic PE headers
    fread(&dosHeader, sizeof(dosHeader), 1, dllFile);
    fseek(dllFile, dosHeader.e_lfanew, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&NtHeaders, sizeof(NtHeaders), 1, dllFile);

    // Search for the executable section, .text section.
    for( i = 0 ; i < NtHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections ; i++ ) {
        fread(&sectionHeader, sizeof(sectionHeader), 1, dllFile);
        // If we found a section that contains executable code,
        // we found our code setion.
        if( (sectionHeader.Characteristics & IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE) != 0 ) {
            printf("[*] Code section: `%s'\n", sectionHeader.Name);
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(dllFile);

    // Load the DLL to get it's base address
    if( (dllHandle = LoadLibraryA(argv[1])) == NULL ) {
        printf("[!] Error: loading the DLL, 0x%.8x\n", (unsigned int) GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    // The code start at : base address + code virtual address
    starAddr = (unsigned char *) dllHandle + sectionHeader.VirtualAddress;
    // It ends at : base address + code virtual address + virtual size
    endAddr = (unsigned char *) starAddr + sectionHeader.Misc.VirtualSize;

    printf("[*] Base address : 0x%.8x\n", (unsigned int) dllHandle);
    printf("[*] Start address: 0x%.8x\n", (unsigned int) starAddr);
    printf("[*] End address  : 0x%.8x\n", (unsigned int) endAddr);

    // Simple liner search, when ever we find `0xff 0xd5' we print that address
    for( endAddr -= sizeof(opcode) ; starAddr < endAddr ; starAddr++ ) {
        if( memcmp(&opcode, (void *) starAddr, sizeof(opcode)) == 0 ) {
            printf("[*] Found `call ebp` at: 0x%.8x\n", (unsigned int) starAddr);
        }
    }

    FreeLibrary(dllHandle);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it and test it with that DLL:

```
> gcc -Wall findopcode.c -o findopcode
> findopcode.exe test.dll
[*] Code section: `.text'
[*] Base address : 0x6bec0000
[*] Start address: 0x6bec1000
[*] End address  : 0x6bec1984
[*] Found `call ebp` at: 0x6bec125a
[*] Found `call ebp` at: 0x6bec1268

>
```

It works pretty well, let's try `user32.dll`:

```
> findopcode.exe \Windows\System32\user32.dll
[*] Code section: `.text'
[*] Base address : 0x75680000
[*] Start address: 0x75681000
[*] End address  : 0x756e86ef
[*] Found `call ebp` at: 0x756b49b5

>
```

I only found one `call ebp` at `0x756b49b5`. Note, you way want to check if you have a read access before you read with `memcmp` using [IsBadReadPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366713%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
        if( IsBadReadPtr(starAddr, sizeof(opcode)) == 0 &&
            memcmp(&opcode, (void *) starAddr, sizeof(opcode)) == 0 ) {
```

so the program won't fail if you hit some area with some weird access.

Comment: Wow!  Excellent answer.  Very helpful and informative.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to use the `msfpescan` from the [metasploit framework](http://www.metasploit.com/):

```
msfpescan -j ebp user32.dll
```